# How do I create multiple instances on the same point at specific intervals?

Tags: geometry-nodes, keyframes, instances

I've been doing a motion graphics project where I'd like a set of markers to move along a curve, to appear at one end of a track, translate across the screen, react when they reach a target, and disappear when they reach the end of the track. So far I've accomplished most of those things, at least with a single marker, and for the most part, procedurally and non-destructively.

[image: da nodes setup, nested at the top in a node group is the marker geometry]

Unfortunately I've hit a bit of a wall. I can't for the life of me figure out how to approach inputting when each marker will appear, and how they will be repeated. Initially, I thought to utilize the `Sample Index` node and the `Instance on Points` selection field input create some kind of makeshift array with booleans and a modulo and scene time. I tried to assemble a makeshift function using the index value of the instances, as well as the points, but I think I perhaps overcomplicated it a bit. I understand I can keyframe basically any value, and I'd like to do that by sending a one signal to create the instanced markers along the track.

[image]

My second approach was to create a single point with which to instance a marker on, then translate that instance across the screen. This is good because I can scale and manipulate the marker as it reaches the target, having a little impact and life, I want to retain this functionality. Using duplicates I can get a simple, regular pattern, but I lack the precise, key framed control to be able to input complex patterns. Not only that, but if I *were* to have per key frame control, I'd need it to apply when the marker hits the target, and *not* when the marker instance is created. I might need to learn some python so I can write some kind of script to find how many frames it would take the marker to reach the target at given framerate and point density, and offset the instancing of markers by that number of frames.

Does anyone know how I would repeat the action of instancing on a point at a specific frame? That way, an instance of the marker would appear at a given coordinate, translate, react to the target, and disappear, just how I have the singular marker setup now. I'd like it to remain pretty much entirely within Geometry Nodes, to maintain control over where these important graphics are, and the path they take to get there. I feel like the solution is right there, just beyond my understanding, or my approach is entirely flawed. I'm still pretty new to blender, so I'd really appreciate a more experienced set of eyes on the problem. thank you! :P